# How do you use CSS column / grid to setup a text and image collage layout?

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am using older Skeleton css version, it is a 16 column grid system. I am trying to setup similar layout as in this picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v6K8.jpg

I am pretty new to CSS, is using two containers (one inside another) a proper method?

Here is a sample code of what I been trying, but not working out too well =(

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="eight columns alpha">
    <div class="image">
      <img alt="" src="images/coffee.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="eight columns omega">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="eight columns">
        <img alt="" src="images/plate.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="eight columns">
        <img alt="" src="images/macaro.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="text area">
        <p class="quote">"One of my favorite parts of using Square Register is being able to talk to customers while I am swiping their cards."</p>

        <p class="name">Norm Mui, Coffee Foundry</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- 2nd container -->
  </div>
</div> <!-- 1st container -->
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your CSS, but maybe this helps you:

HTML:

// The class "columns" is your "block" (div) that needs the content. I've made a CSS with a background-color, height and width.

// In that div "columns we create new "columns, numbered by 1,2 and 3. I've floated all the text to the left and gived it a margin. The first, second and the third a margin of 15px ( top, right, buttom and left ).

// In the div column "columns" I have made a textarea with also a margin of 15px. The vertical-align is for a top vertical align. with the display we means that it needs to be in the block, with a margin of 40% ( it takes 40% of the block).

```
 <div id="container">
      <div class="columns">

          <div class="eight-columns-1">
        <img alt="" src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/04/10/11752526/gI_134971_best-image-web-hosting.png">
      </div>

      <div class="eight-columns-2">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.causingeffect.com/images/made/images/example/cow_100_100_c1.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="eight-columns-3">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.causingeffect.com/images/made/images/example/cow_100_100_c1.jpg">
      </div>    

        <div class="textarea">
        <p class="quote">"One of my favorite parts of using Square Register is being able to talk to customers while I am swiping their cards."</p>

        <p class="name">Norm Mui, Coffee Foundry</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.columns {background-color:yellow; width: 530px; height: 285px;}

.eight-columns-1 {float:left; margin: 15px;}

.eight-columns-2 {float: left; margin: 15px;}

.eight-columns-3 {float:left; margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;}

.textarea {vertical-align:top; margin: 15px; display:inline-block; width: 40%;}
```

Comment: Dear @Arjan, thank you for the answer. However, a little explanation why and how your answer solves the problem would be great instead of plain code.

Comment: Hi @Arpi, Thanks for your comment. I just added some explanation.